# Laravel Relationships HasOneThrough

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Currently, I'm hardcoding DB queries in my Models to handle table relationships. I'd like to take advantage of Laravel's Eloquent relationships instead.

I have 3 Models (Property, Landlord, Tenant), which are all joined to each other in one way or another. I have 2 intermediate tables (TenantProperty, LandlordProperty) which holds relationship id's.

The pivot tables hold important contractStart/contractEnd data, which is vital for future remittances to be generated.

Property table:

```
------------------------
|       id|   propTitle|
------------------------
|        1|  Property 1|
------------------------
|        2|  Property 2|
```

Landlord table:

```
------------------------
|       id|   firstName|
------------------------
|        1|         Bob|
------------------------
|        2|       Roger|
```

Tenant table:

```
------------------------
|       id|   firstName|
------------------------
|        1|         Ted|
------------------------
|        2|       Peter|
```

TenantProperty table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|       id|   tenant_id|   property_id|contractStart| contractEnd
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|        1|           1|             2|   01-01-1970|  01-01-1971
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|        2|           2|             1|   01-01-1970|  01-01-1971
```

LandlordProperty table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|       id| landlord_id|   property_id|contractStart| contractEnd
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|        1|           1|             1|   01-01-1970|  01-01-1970
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|        2|           2|             2|   01-01-1973|  01-01-1973
```

My question is; Is it possible to have a `hasOneThrough` as opposed to `hasManyThrough` ?

An example of my Models:

```
    class Tenant extends TenantModel 
    {
        public function tenantProperty() {
            return $this->hasOne('App\TenantProperty');
        }
    }

    class Property extends TenantModel
    {
        public function tenant()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\TenantProperty');
        }
    }

    class Landlord extends TenantModel
    {
        public function properties(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\LandlordProperty');
        }
    }

    class LandlordProperty extends TenantModel
    {
        public function property(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Property');
        }

        public function landlord(){
            return $this->hasOne('App\Landlord');
        }
    }

    class TenantProperty extends TenantModel
    {
        public function tenant() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Tenant');
        }

        public function property(){
            public function product() {
                return $this->belongsTo('App\Property');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited - Since you require the start_date and end_date, you can only consider this obvious that the last entry for that current property is the active one. Therefore, instead of going for a HasManyThrough, I am sure this will be a  better approach for handling all kinds of cases possible :)

```
landlords
id | landlord_name
---|--------------
1  |   landmine1
2  |   landmine2

tenants
id | tenant_name
---|--------------
1  |    haha
2  |    hehe
3  |    hoho

properties
id | property_name | 
---|---------------|
1  |   abc         |
2  |   abcd        |
3  |   abcde       |

landlord_property
id | property_id | landlord_id | start_date | end_date
---|-------------|-------------|------------|---------
1  |   1         |    1        |  SomeDate  | SomeDate
2  |   1         |    2        |  SomeDate  | SomeDate
3  |   2         |    1        |  SomeDate  | SomeDate

property_tenant
id | property_id | tenant_id   | start_date | end_date
---|-------------|-------------|------------|---------
1  |   1         |    1        |  SomeDate  | SomeDate
2  |   2         |    1        |  SomeDate  | SomeDate
3  |   1         |    2        |  SomeDate  | SomeDate
```

There is no need of intermediate/pivot table in this case

```
class Property extends Model
{
  public function landlords()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Landlord');
  }

  public function tenants()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tenant');
  }
}

class Tenant extends Model 
{
  public function properties()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Property');
  }

  public function landlord()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Landlord');
  }
}

class Landlord extends Model
{
  public function properties()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Property');
  }

  public function tenants()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tenant');
  }
}
```

Now you can easily do

```
$landlord = Landlord::find(1);
$propertiesOfLandlord = $landlord->properties;

$tenantsOfProperty = collect();

foreach($propertiesOfLandlord as $property) {
  $currentTenant = $property->tenants->last();
  if($currentTenant) {        
    $tenantsOfProperty->push($currentTenant);
  }
}

$property = Property::find(1);
$landlordsOfProperty = $property->landlords;
$tenantsOfProperty = $property->tenants;

$tenant = Tenant::find(1);
$propertiesOfTenant = $tenant->properties;
$landlordOfTenant = $tenant->properties()
                           // ->wherePivot('property_id', 1) If searching for a particular property of tenant
                           ->last()
                           ->landlords
                           ->last();
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it cleared in my initial post. I need to record contractStart/contractEnd dates for landlord and tenants, so remittances can be generated, so it is essential that pivot tables are used.

Comment: @MikeF Just edited my answer... This should be able to handle all kinds of cases for you :)