# Unable to access relationship Laravel HasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model

I have 5 models, 2 are pivot/intermediary models.

`Tenant`,`Landlord`,`Property`,`LandlordProperty`,`TenantProperty`

Landlord & Tenant need to be accessible both from within the Property model and also exclusively.

Currently, I am unable to access the Landlord model from Property, it simply returns no data.

Tables:

Property table:

```
------------------------
|       id|   propTitle|
------------------------
|        1|  Property 1|
------------------------
|        2|  Property 2|
```

Landlord table:

```
------------------------
|       id|   firstName|
------------------------
|        1|         Bob|
------------------------
|        2|       Roger|
```

Tenant table:

```
------------------------
|       id|   firstName|
------------------------
|        1|         Ted|
------------------------
|        2|       Peter|
```

TenantProperty table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|       id|   tenant_id|   property_id|contractStart| contractEnd
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|        1|           1|             2|   01-01-1970|  01-01-1971
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|        2|           2|             1|   01-01-1970|  01-01-1971
```

LandlordProperty table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|       id| landlord_id|   property_id|contractStart| contractEnd
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|        1|           1|             1|   01-01-1970|  01-01-1970
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|        2|           2|             2|   01-01-1973|  01-01-1973
```

Models:

```
class Landlord extends TenantModel {
    public function properties(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Property', 'App\LandlordProperty',
            'property_id', 'id', 'id');
    }
}

class Tenant extends TenantModel {
    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Property', 'App\TenantProperty',
            'property_id', 'id', 'id');
    }
}

class Property extends TenantModel {
    public function landlords()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Landlord', 'App\LandlordProperty',
             'landlord_id', 'id', 'landlord_id');
    }

    public function getLandlordAttribute()
    {
        return $this->landlords->first();
    }

    public function tenant()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Tenant', 'App\TenantProperty',
             'tenant_id', 'id', 'property_id');
    }
}

class TenantProperty extends TenantModel {
    public function tenant() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tenant');
    }

    public function property(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Property');
    }
}

class LandlordProperty extends TenantModel {
    public function property(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Property');
    }

    public function landlord(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Landlord');
    }
}
```

The following loop returns no data on `$property->landlords` and I am unsure why

```
@foreach ($properties as $property)

    <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="/property/view/{{ $property->id }}">
        <td>{{ $property->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $property->streetAddress }}</td>
        <td>{{ $property->type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $property->firstName }} {{ $property->lastName }}</td>
        @php

            echo '<pre>' . var_export($property->landlords, true) . '</pre>';
        @endphp
        <td>
        @php
            if($property->status == 1){
                echo "<b style='color: green;'>Active</b>";
            }else{
                echo "<b style='color: red;'>Disabled</b>";
            }
        @endphp
        </td>
        <td>{{ date('d M Y', strtotime($property->created_at)) }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

*** EDIT 1 ***

Ok, so adjusting the `App\Property landlords() function` to:

```
public function landlords()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Landlord', 'App\LandlordProperty',
         'property_id', 'id', 'id');
}
```

Now starts returning some data, but it's inconsistent.

It is looping over IDs from the `LandlordProperty` table, rather than pulling data for the relevant property ID.

- Property #1 -> LandlordProperty #1 -> Landlord #1
- Property #2 -> LandlordProperty #2 -> Landlord #2
- Property #11 -> LandlordProperty #3 -> Landlord #3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Relationships HasOneThrough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822659/laravel-relationships-hasonethrough)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are making mistake as in general a property has only one lanlord but has many tenants. so landlord and property are in hasMany relation.

i suggest you to delete LandlordProperty table and create a lanlord_id foreign key in the property table. now create public functions as below:

in lanlord model:

```
public function properties()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Property::class)
}
```

in property model:

```
public function landlord()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Landlord::class)
}
```

now try to query.

Comment: The trouble is, sometimes properties are sold and a new landlord is appointed. If this is the case, I need the contractStart & contractEnd dates for remittances.

Comment: @mike as i can understand contact dates are bind to properties or tenent table. so you first fetch the contract details and then update the the table with new landlord_id and new dates.

Comment: @MikeF to update the landlord_id while creating the foreign use {code} ->onUpdate('cascade') at the end of foreign key so that it can permit you to update the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this, by using `belongsToMany`, as set out below:

```
class Tenant extends TenantModel
{
    public function property()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Property', 'tenant_property', 'property_id', 'tenant_id')->withPivot('isActive','contractStart','contractEnd', 'property_id');
    }
}

class Property extends TenantModel
{

    public function landlord()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Landlord', 'landlord_property', 'property_id', 'landlord_id')->withPivot('isActive','date_from','date_to', 'property_id');
    }

    public function tenant()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tenant', 'tenant_property', 'property_id', 'tenant_id')->withPivot('isActive','contractStart','contractEnd', 'property_id','vacatedDate');
    }
}

class Landlord extends TenantlModel
{
    public function property(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Property', 'landlord_property', 'landlord_id', 'property_id')->withPivot('isActive','date_from','date_to', 'property_id');
    }
}
```

This has also got rid of the issue of having intermediary controllers, as I'm using pivot tables